# Under GDPR, why is google not considering the index entries as personal data?

Tags: gdpr, google

I have a fairly unique name and never came across, online or otherwise, anyone with the same name and spelling.

Following this, I make the assumption that this qualifies as personal data under GDPR since my name and first name uniquely identify me as far as it can be tested.

When I request my personal data from google, I got about 2gb. Mostly my emails and, in the end, nothing really valuable.

I'm using iOS for all mobile activity and I don't have chrome, so it probably limited data capture.

The surprise was that they had a list of flights I made and I'm not sure how this was captured.

But my question is about the index: I can be found under the index and my name, the "personal data", has to be part of their database index.

So, under GDPR, I should get a copy of the index entries when my name appears, shouldn't I?

Also, if this constitute "personal data", shouldn't I have the ability to request either:

- deletion, under the right to be forgotten
- or, stop processing, where they can keep data but not use it?

It looks like Google is considering everything but the index under GDPR.

Is there an interpretation of the law that allows this?

Comment: Why just public information?  What about the information other people hold about you in their Gmail or Google Drive accounts?

Comment: @Moo, it's a good point; interestingly, when they gave me my list of contacts, I had a list of thumb photos, for each contact, but no name / contact info.

Answer (score 2):

Individual search results can certainly include your personal data. Nevertheless, excluding these from the response to a data subject access request seems sensible. Possible arguments:

- The information in search results is not associated with your account; consequently a copy of the data in the account does not include search results.
- You can obtain a copy of this data yourself by using the search functionality, it is therefore unnecessary to include it in a download. (Note that the right to data portability is often conflated with the right to access, but access does not require a machine-readable format.)
- Personal data in search results is difficult to attribute to a particular person since multiple people might have the same name and one person might use multiple names. To avoid the inclusion of wrong information, such attribution should only be done manually.
- The data in search results is only processed as textual data, not as personal data. (Not quite true since websites might be literally linked to a person, but that isn't the case in general.) Similarly, a postal service does not process the personal data in the mail they deliver.
- A request to access to the search index is unfounded and excessive, and may therefore be refused.

Google does somewhat implement the right to be forgotten, but correctly points out that their index merely reflects the websites on the internet, and to actually remove the data you need to get it taken down from the websites that published it.

Comment: Regarding the last point, if I consent that site 'x' has a copy of a discussion I had with someone else, in which I disclose personal information, it doesn't mean I consent for google to have a copy of that same discussion. The fact it is public data doesn't mean I consent for google to hold a copy of it; To me, it feels like the 'public data' reasoning is a way for them to try to escape responsibility.

Comment: @Thomas I'd *have* to disagree with you there - restricting use of public information in the way you describe would utterly destroy the internet.  The GDPR (and the right to be forgotten) is bad enough as it is, but your approach there is well beyond that - public data is public data, and anyone who can access it should be able to use it.  You are basically saying that every site on the internet should be a closed community akin to Facebook (where site indexing is prohibited unless you have explicit permission), AOL or Compuserve.

Comment: no, I understand the value of sharing data, but at the same time I think a person's privacy is more important. For example, 10 years ago I had a public conversation in a bar, everyone around could hear it. But only a few people were present. Now someone decides to go back in time and make that conversation public to people that didn't even know me back then. In my eyes it is generally ok, unless a party to that conversation objects. If I post something on a site, most of the world doesn't know about it, but google decides that the world should know about it and I have nothing to say about it

Comment: Where I take issue is that they make an unilateral decision about things that were done in a specific context (site in this case), would be forgotten, and bring them back to life in a totally unrelated context. In my specific case, there is some inaccurate information regarding my family that was posted by an ex in 2006 on a forgotten, but still online blog. It hasn't been updated for more than 10 years, the admin is not there anymore, it's a zombie hosting account with no visitors, but google decided this should be public and brought up to anyone that would look me up.

Comment: @Thomas that zombie hosting account is what makes your data public, not Google. Can't you find it in other search engines e.g. DuckDuckGo?

Comment: no, it's not listed there, nor in bing; but it may just be that their index is smaller. Yes, that site is the origin of the problem, but google is magnifying it. It's a genealogy site dedicated to a few family trees! it's a super small thing that no one would have a chance to find without google. To take an example: let's say you do a compromising polaroid, forget the photo in a bar.. it's fine, it'll disappear in due time, only people in the vicinity could see it. Google finds it, puts in on first page of the newspaper, everyday for the rest of your life and you have nothing to say.

Comment: public doesn't mean 'has to be broadcasts to everybody', public things can have a locality. For example, I'm currently doing a lawsuit against a company on a small island. It's public data, but widely ignored because it's not really interesting in the end. In that case now, people on the other side of the planet can know I haven't been paid for some work I did, how much it was, etc.. is that really 'public interest'? in the end it's made public to inform people related to that situation, not to inform people that I met once that google me. Public doesn't mean it should be broadcasted.

Comment: @Thomas there has to be an element of personal responsibility involved - if you have a public conversation and someone overhears it, *you cannot control what third parties do with that information*.  If you tell your friend something, you cannot stop them from publishing that information.  You are advocating for a situation where "public" isn't "public" but a grey area that is defined with handwaving depending on your feelings.

Comment: @Thomas if you have issue with inaccurate information, then the "right to be forgotten" is the avenue with which you take to correct the public record.  As Greendrake says, Google didnt make anything public, they took public information and made it searchable - thats a very different situation.  Google isnt broadcasting anything, there is no feed to which everyone is subscribed to on which this information is published, it doesnt appear in a Google version of a Facebook feed - they are taking public information and pointing people to it when they enter certain search terms.  Thats fine.

Comment: In real life, public has a 'radius' where people can see/hear/participate, whatever I do will generally not reach the other side of the planet; on websites, the information has a radius as well since we are generally not confronted with things we don't look for. Then a few businesses decided that, for their profit, everything has an unlimited radius with a perpetual duration and put the burden of managing one's privacy on every single person. I don't deny the huge benefits of indexing, but the ultimate decision should be in the participant's hands.

Comment: If I have a conversation with you, in a restaurant, and everyone can overhear it, it still doesn't mean it should be in the papers the next day for all our friends to see. They weren't in that bar and we don't expect them to get a transcript of it. Google's vision of 'public' is that every moment you're not inside your home (and that's changing quick), they have a right to report your activities to everyone else. Someone cataloging everyone's trashcans, on public ground, and sending a summary to everyone, would have a very hard time with people, but we accept the digital version of it.

Comment: @Thomas you are trying to apply the basics of personal space to the internet - that doesnt work, and will never work, and in any case there is utterly nothing you can do from stopping anyone in your personal space from publishing that conversation to the internet.  Your view on what Google is doing is utterly utterly wrong as a result.  Google isnt cataloging anyones trashcans, they are cataloging things people have put up on notice boards for anyone to read.

Comment: I believe we disagree because I think that 'being able to' is dramatically different from 'systematically doing it'. Where I live we don't have proper noise legislation, I have full legal right to make my neighbor's life unbearable, but I don't do it. If one person moves here and does it, even if it is his full right, I wouldn't support. For this reason, I think GDPR is a great step forward, I would support any law that supports control of personal data by the owner of that data. In my case, Google's 'rights' are turning a small problem into a larger one and they don't make it easy to fix.

Comment: @Thomas Google doesn't need your consent, they can rely on a *legitimate interest* or perhaps even *public interest* legal basis to index that public data. In some cases, you can ask Google to block search results. Still, the best approach would be to target the site publishing this inaccurate information, or that information's author. Note that this brushes up against free speech issues depending on how that inaccurate information is presented, so deletion is not guaranteed – GDPR doesn't help you censor people.

Comment: Isn't this a bit of a paradox? Without both access to your personal information and the ability to process it, things you don't want it to have, Google is incapable of modifying its search to no index websites with information about you.

Comment: @zeroone You are right that this seems backwards. But Google has a legitimate interest to index public websites. Perhaps viewing this as a Restriction of Processing is more appropriate: data is not deleted, but annotated to prevent certain kinds of processing (like showing the index entry in a search result for the person's name). The GDPR cares about lawful processing, but does not give a right to leave no trace.

Comment: Interestingly, google isn't taking down indexes to their cached content on request. I had my full name in a profile once, and I removed the name, but Google still points to the profile when I google my name, and showed the original profile text quite a long time. So that's actually another dimension added to the discussion.